# about rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, url-routing

if i use

```
namespace :helpcenter do
  get "hh/logout"
  get 'hh/login'
end
```

it will match the url helpcenter/hh/logout

my question is how to let these method mapping to the url /hh/logout didn't contains the module name

Comment: Don't really understand your question. What do you want to achieve? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: So you wanted to match `/hh/logout` to `herlpercenter_controller` or `helpercenter::hh_controller` or `hh_controller`? Your original case would use `helpcenter::hh_controller`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a scope to achieve this:

```
scope :module => 'helpcenter' do
  resources :articles
end
```

This will generate a mapping for `/articles`, `/articles/new` etc and not `helpcenter/articles`. It will however still route to the articles controller in the helpcenter namespace. e.g.: `app/controllers/helpcenter/articles_controller.rb`

Hope that helps.